# winapi - resource file, dialog units

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, pixel

I have dialog which width and height is specified in .rc (resource file).

For example:

```
ErrorDialog DIALOG  10, 10, 300, 110
STYLE WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER
CAPTION "Error!" 
{
    CTEXT "Select One:", 1, 10, 10, 280, 12
    PUSHBUTTON "&Retry", 2, 75, 30, 60, 12
    PUSHBUTTON "&Abort", 3, 75, 50, 60, 12
   PUSHBUTTON "&Ignore", 4, 75, 80, 60, 12
}
```

Everything works OK, but when I try it to another computer, dialog don't looks like in my computer. It is bigger and buttons are not in correct place in dialog.

I found that dialog units are dependent on system font size, but I don't know if this thing causes the problem.

If yes, how can I solve this problem to have same look of dialog.

I try it into same resolution of monitor on both computers, so problem is not with resolution.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of both, so that we know what you expect the other computer to show?

Comment: What do you mean "not in correct place"? Are they not one under another, at the same horizontal position? Your dialog may scale depending on the DPI setting, and this is normal. Are you doing pixel-based calculation / position adjustment at run time?

Comment: not in corrent place means - I have for example one button which is in center of dialog window. When I show this dialog window in second computer, than dialog have different width and height and my button is not in center of this dialog window but more in left. I don't move with button programmatically. I center it on my computer by setting the position of button in .rc.

Comment: I found, that this can be connected with DPI-aware. How can I make resistant application to settings of DPI ([setting](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC707861.png))